# Scrolling when idle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone point me to an example of code for a page that begins to automatically scroll when the user is idle for an amount of time? I think this is slightly beyond my skill set. I think JQuery or something similar might be appropriate but I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm designing a site for the nonprofit I work for and we don't have the money to hire a programmer. I wouldn't ask anyone to code anything for me, just to point me in the right direction. Thank you so much.

Julie K.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something quick and dirty that will do what you want.  I currently have it set to 2 seconds idle time, but you can change that as you wish.

```
var now = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
    var nnow = new Date();
    if(nnow.getTime() - now.getTime() >= 2000)
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: '+=50'}, 2000, 'linear');
    }, 2000);
$(document)
    .mousemove(function(){ now = new Date(); $('body').stop(); })
    .keypress(function(){ now = new Date(); $('body').stop(); });
```

Edit: added .stop in mousemove and keypress events to stop scrolling immediately when user moves mouse or presses a key, rather than waiting for animation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would definitely help here.

You should handle the keyboard and mouse events to catch user activity.

Then, whenever you see activity, call `setTimeout` to make your code run 2 minutes after the activity.  Save the return value of the `setTimeout` call in a global variable, and call `clearTimeout` on it before `setTimeout` to clear the last timeout.

For example: (Using jQuery and the [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin)

```
var timeout = false;
$(document.body).bind('keydown keyup mousemove mouseup', function() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(userIsIdle, 120000);    //120,000 milliseconds
});
function userIsIdle() {
    $(document.body).scrollTo('100%', 100000);
}
```

Comment: You should catch somehow the scrolling without mouse or keyboard. Otherwise readers with touch screens or voice control (Opera) are getting a hard time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a plugin like [this](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery), and set it to use JavaScripts setTimeout() function to trigger it, which could reset every time you detect certain user actions, such as keyDown and Click.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define what you mean by IDLE, I will assume that the user is not moving mouse for x amount of time.
Here are the steps pseudo js.

```
 var lastTime=0;
var threshold=60000 ; // 1min
var howOftenToCheck = 1000;//1 sec
var inter = 0;
inter = setInterval(function() {
    var delta=lastTime-currentTime;
    if(delta>threashold){
        clearInterval(inter);       
        window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos);
    }
}, howOftenToCheck);
```

This should give you a general idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think `onBlur` event is what you're looking for, so you can do like this :

```
<body onblur="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');">
```

You can change the 0 to the vertical position where you want to scroll to.

Note: this will fire the scrolling when you go to other page or tab or where you can't see the page.

Answer (score -1):

use the following jQuery functions to scroll the page's body

```
// Scrolling Down
$('body').animate({
scrollTop: '-=300px'
}, 2000);

// Scrolling Up
$('body').animate({
scrollTop: '+=300px'
}, 2000);
```